# WebSocket connection to 'wss://hostname/' failed:

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I'm trying to get a connection between my client and server. My website (client) is hosted on digitalocean.com with vps hosting. On google chrome i get message "WebSocket connection to 'wss://hostname/' failed:"
and on microsoft edge "WebSocket connection to 'wss://hostname/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200"

html client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        location /foo/ {
            
        }
        
        const ws = new WebSocket("wss://hostname");
        
        ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
            console.log("something")
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

node js server

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const path = require('path');

const server = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'hostname.crt')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.key'))
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server})

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    ws.send('something');
});

server.listen(443, "0.0.0.0",function () {
    console.log('Server is listening on 443');
});
```

Comment: Is ```ws://hostname``` working for you?

Comment: @hulkinBrain that gives me message "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hostname' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://hostname'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS."

and

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
    at https://hostname/:15:20